# Using pThreads, is it possible to write a function that can detect what thread it's being called from?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

This is the usage case:

```
Log(char* s); // prints out a log message
```

Now:

```
Log("hello world\n"); // called from Thread1
```

Desired output:

```
Thread1: hello world
```

Now:

```
Log("hello world\n"); // called from Thread2
```

Desired output:

```
Thread2: hello world
```

I can have a map that maps thread pids to strings. What I need however, is a function that when called form different threads gives me unique identification tags. Is this possible?

Thanks!

(Langauge: C/C++)

Comment: The subject is wrong, you need the current thread, not the caller function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to pass `pthread_self()` into your Log() function (or write a macro).

Comment: Another method is `&errno`. This is portable to all sane threading systems, not just POSIX threads.

Answer (score 1):

One clean way to do it would be to create a thread attribute (using pthread_attr_*) for the thread name, set the attribute in each thread, then read it in the log function.

You could also use pthread_self in the log function.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You can't create arbitrary custom attributes with strings attached.